# Dynamic SiteMap, BreadCrumb Based Off of Multiple Tables

Tags: asp.net, coldfusion, parent-child, sitemap, breadcrumbs

I have about 20 different tables that each have a different parent / child relationship built into them. I've recently been asked to create a breadcrumb and Site Map for our website based off of all of these tables.

One idea I had, was to remove the parent / child relationship from each of these tables and create basically one table that holds the id and parentId and whenever I need to pull the parent child relationship I would just join the parent_child_relationships table to whatever table I was pulling from specifically.

Does this make sense?

Anyway, the problem with this idea is that i don't like it. haha.

Does anyone else have any other ideas of how this could be done? Or what the correct way of building a breadcrumb and sitemap based off of a site comprised of 20 tables or so?

If it helps, my site is comprised of asp.net, ColdFusion and uses a MSSQL database.

Thanks!

Comment: Basing your site navigation off of your table structure often leads to usability issues. The technical backend of an app is not so important to the end-user. I would approach the navigation (breadcrumbs, info arch, etc.) independently of your table structure.

Comment: Then your job as a developer is to execute that 'vision' - tie the front-end and back-end together :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not let the implementation of the UI effect the design of your model and especially not your DB.  Prototype the front end, involve your customer(s), give them a voice.  Build your breadcrumbs and site map without it initially tied into your actual DB.  Once your customer says "thats what we want, just like that", then freeze the prototype, then work on the actual implementation - how will your app request the data, what type of dataobject will you use AND THEN build your db,

"One idea I had, was to remove the parent / child relationship from each of these tables and create basically one table that holds the id and parentId"

This is not a very scalable solution, do not *reverse normalize your db. Follow standard relation database modeling/normalization techniques. Lots of small cohensive tables with lots of association tables.